# configure Mac OS X AudioUnit to provide SignedInteger samples

Tags: macos, signal-processing, core-audio, audiounit

I am writing a Mac OS X application to capture some audio through the microphone with echo cancellation. I am creating an AudioUnit of type VoiceProcessingIO. I want to output the audio as Signed Integer Linear PCM. However, when I indicate that I want the output sample format to  record as SignedInteger, I get an "Unsupported Format" error.

How can I configure the AudioUnit to output data in the signed integer format? Here is how I am configuring it right now. If I try replacing kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat with kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger, then I get an error :(

```
AudioComponentDescription desc;
desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO;
desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
desc.componentFlags = 0;
desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

AudioComponent comp = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

OSStatus status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(comp, &_audioUnit);
```

...

```
const int sampleSize = 2;
const int eight_bits_per_byte = 8;
AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat;
streamFormat.mSampleRate = 16000;
streamFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
streamFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
streamFormat.mBytesPerPacket = sampleSize;
streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame = sampleSize;
streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
streamFormat.mBitsPerChannel = sampleSize * eight_bits_per_byte;

status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &streamFormat, sizeof(streamFormat));
```

// status = UnsupportedFormatError

Answer (score 0):

I decided that I can't do it. I used the AudioConverter class to convert the floating point format to signed integer. On the bright side, AudioConverter is surprisingly easy to use!